# Using module_invoke for Menu causes Undefined index notice

Tags: blocks, navigation

I'm displaying a multi-level menu in the footer of my site using:

```
$block = module_invoke('menu', 'block_view', 'main-menu');
          print render($block['content']);
```

Which is displaying correctly, however I am receiving this warning message:

> Notice: Undefined index: main-menu in menu_block_view() (line 486 of /****/modules/menu/menu.module).

Any suggestions on how to suppress this message?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused from the following line, executed from [`menu_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21menu%21menu.module/function/menu_block_view/7.x).

```
$data['subject'] = check_plain($menus[$delta]);
```

$delta is the value you pass as last argument to `module_invoke()`.

It means there isn't any menu with that ID, or you misspelled the menu ID. Try with main_menu, for example.

Comment: Strange, it's what I thought, however the menu is actually being displayed as is.  So I am getting the right content, but an error is being recorded anyways.

Comment: For a notice like that, it is probable PHP is using a default value for that array index, such as an empty string for a string, or 0 for an integer. If you are seeing what you are expecting, it just means the default value assigned from PHP matches the value expected from the code. Not checking if an array index is defined is still a bad coding habit, though, even if the code is currently producing the expected result. (It could produce the wrong result in future.)